# Authenticate a use using Angular and Laravel passport with grant_type authorization_code

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

What i'am trying to do is setting up an authentication system for my website using Laravel passport as back-end and Angular as front-end

From the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passport#requesting-tokens) I understood that I first need to make a GET Request to /oauth/authorize route with the following data:

```
      'client_id' : 1,
      'redirect_uri' : `${this.baseURL}`,
      'response_type' : 'code',
      'scope' : '',
      'state' : random_string(40)
```

and then make a POST request to /oauth/token endpoint with the code generated from the previous response to require an access_token

At the current state thou when I make the first request (/oauth/authorize) using postman, Laravel responds with this error:

`Route [login] not defined.`

From what I reed, I need first to authenticate the user in some ways before requesting for authorization to the endpoint but I cannot find out how to do this.

Do I need to define some login logic? like a login function in my controller that should do something with my user data?

ADDITIONAL INFOS:
-I am trying to authenticate users coming from my front-end so they are first-party users

-I don't want to use "password grant tokens" as it's  not recommended by the docs

Comment: What are your request headers?

Comment: No request headers passed, but I don’t think it’s the reason

Comment: oh, sorry, didn't read the question correctly. Did you publish passport views? Maybe view has a link or button towards `route('login')`, but you do not have this route

Comment: I did not use passport views I'm using angular for my front-end so the form should be defined as an angular component, what am I doing here thou is testing the api with passport and i'have not completely understood how should I manage the process of logging a user in

Comment: Try to add header Accept: application/json to your get request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to send a GET request every time to receive tokens of the authentication system, since they are static and are generated when the command is executed: [php artisan passport:install](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passport#creating-a-password-grant-client).

This data is stored in a table (schema) of the database **oauth_clients**.

You can write them, for example, in the environments of the Angular app and use them without making unnecessary requests to the server and database every time. If, of course, Personal Access Client and Password Grant Client tokens are constantly updated, for example, by CRON, then of course, in this case it is necessary and it makes sense to send a preliminary GET request to the server.

**And the code for the client part of the authentication system will be as follows:**

*services/auth/auth.service*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
import { catchError, tap } from 'rxjs/operators'

interface IResponseHTTPLogin { // can be placed in a separate module or model at the discretion
  token_type: string
  expires_in: number
  access_token: string
  refresh_token: string
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  /**
   * Auth Laravel Passport: Password Grant Client
   *
   * @private
   */
  private clientSecret: string = 'YOUR client secret token from oauth_clients table()' // <-- add enviroments
  private clientId: number = 2 // <-- id client from oauth_clients table() | add enviroments

  constructor (private http: HttpClient) {}

  /**
   * Login in cabinet.
   *
   * @param email
   * @param password
   */
  login (email: string, password: string) {
    return this.http.post<IResponseHTTPLogin>('/oauth/token', {
      grant_type: 'password',
      client_id: this.clientId,
      client_secret: this.clientSecret,
      username: email,
      password
    })
      .pipe(
        tap(({ access_token, refresh_token }) => {
          if (access_token) {
            this.setToken(access_token)
            this.setRefreshToken(refresh_token)
          }
        }),
        catchError((err) => {
          throw new Error(err)
        })
      )
  }

  getToken (): string {
    return sessionStorage.getItem('token') ?? ''
  }

  getRefreshToken (): string {
    return sessionStorage.getItem('token_refresh') ?? ''
  }

  protected setToken (token: string): void {
    sessionStorage.setItem('token', token) // OR use localStorage
  }

  protected setRefreshToken (refresh_token: string): void {
    sessionStorage.setItem('token_refresh', refresh_token)
  }

  isAuthenticate (): boolean {
    return !!sessionStorage.getItem('token')
  }

  logout (): void {
    sessionStorage.removeItem('token')
    sessionStorage.removeItem('token_refresh')
  }
}
```

*interceptor/token.interceptor*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor
} from '@angular/common/http'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth/auth.service'

@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor (private authService: AuthService) {}

  intercept (request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    if (this.authService.isAuthenticate()) {
      request = request.clone({ setHeaders: { Authorization: `Bearer ${this.authService.getToken()}` } })
    }
    return next.handle(request)
  }
}
```

**Very important! In order for your authorization request to be fulfilled and there are no CORS errors, it must be redirected to your backend, for example using the following approach using a proxy.**

*At the root of the project, create a proxy.conf.json file. Where to add the following code:*

```
{
  "/oauth/token": {
    "target": "ADRESS YOR DOMAIN",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
  },
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "ADRESS YOR DOMAIN",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
  },
}
```

*Next, tell Angular that all requests need to be proxied, for this, in package.json in the scripts section, specify:*

```
 ...
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json", <------
 ...
```

*In the AuthServiceProvider backend you can customize your tokens in the boot() method:*

```
...
Passport::tokensExpireIn(now()->addHours(24));
Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn(now()->addDays(30));
Passport::personalAccessTokensExpireIn(now()->addDays(30));
...
```

Functionality testing in development environment:

- Laravel ^9.48
- laravel-passport ^11.5.1
- Angular ^15

I think you will find my answer helpful. If something is not clear, ask!